# Parsing a python file to find classes with certain label

Tags: python, class, parsing

I have a python file with many classes in it. The file looks something like that:

```
some code, functions and stuff...
class A():
     some code...
@label
class B(A):
     some code...
@label
class C(A):
    some code...
class D(A):
    some code...
some extra code...
```

What I want to do is to make a list of all the classes that has the @label before their declaration, i.e in this example: [B,C]. (That will happen in another file, if it matters)

What I tried so far is parsing the file like it was a regular text file (with read() and stuff), but what I get is a list of the classes name and not the classes themselves, i.e  (['B','C']) and I don't know what to do next. I would really hope there's a more elegant way. My next step, after I get that classes list, is to activate for each of the classes a certain function they all have. That's why the name of the class isn't enough for me.

Comment: Take a look at the `ast` module, which parses the python file using python's built in parser.

Comment: Also [**`inspect`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).

Comment: Do you have access/can change the decorators source code?

Comment: I can't change the decorators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

- use the [`tokenize` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) to look out for `token.OP` tokens with the value `@`, followed by `token.NAME` tokens for `label` and, after a newline token, `class`. This is the most light-weight.
- use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse the source into a tree, then use the `ast.walk()` function, looking for `ast.ClassDef` objects. If the object has a `ast.Name` object with `id == 'label'` in the `decorator_list` attribute, you can record the `name` attribute.

The latter is probably easiest:

```
import ast

def labelled_classnames(source):
    module = ast.parse(source)
    for node in ast.walk(module):
        if not isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
            continue
        if any(isinstance(n, ast.Name) and n.id == 'label' 
               for n in node.decorator_list):
            yield node.name
```

Demo:

```
>>> demosource = '''
... class A():
...     pass
...
... @label
... class B(A):
...     pass
...
... @label
... class C(A):
...     pass
...
... class D(A):
...     pass
... '''
>>> list(labelled_classnames(demosource))
['B', 'C']
```